# Recursive JSON Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I want to do a handlebars template with a recursive JSON, but I dont know what are the keys of the JSON (could change), Also I need an IF statment, that one is working. Is any way to create a Helper to do it? Now my answer is an [object object]. This is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/deherinu/dvn4076h/

My JSON:

```
var json={
"results": [
 {
   "collection": "employer",
   "summary":{
     "person": [
       { "name": "My name" },
       { "lastname": "My lastname" },
       { "address": "Street" }
     ],
     "job": "CEO"
   }
 },
 {
   "collection": "employer",
   "summary":{
     "person": [
       { "name": "My name" },
       { "lastname": "My lastname" },
       { "address": "Street" }
     ],
     "job": "Administrator"
   }
 },
 {
   "collection": "company",
   "summary": "Company1"
 },
 {
   "collection": "company",
   "summary": "Company2"
 }
   ]
 };
```

[image: My output]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content around the `person` object.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    {{#results}}
    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase;">{{collection}}</h3>
    {{#xif " collection == 'employer' " }}
    {{#summary}}
    {{#person}}
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {{#each this}}
          <tr>
            <td><b>{{@key}}</b></td>
            <td>{{this}}</td>
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    {{/person}}
    {{/summary}}
    {{else}}
    <div>
      {{summary}}
    </div>
    {{/xif}}
    {{/results}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Thusitha , the problem is that I don't know the name of the key, could be "person" could be another one.

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to bind data without knowing the input data format.